# How do I write an edit-file for mixed data in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, mern

I want to update an article with image.
I am using a mern-stack with redux-toolkit.
I tried to bring the data from the database into the inputfields by using useEffect() and that works, and currently I get no error anymore, but when I press update, I get an alert:

> localhost:3000 includes undefined

and then the pending of my updatefunction stops. So nothing is updated. The preview of my picture works.
Can someone of the experienced people tell me the right way, to write this edit file?

Here is my react-component(current state):

```
 const MainnewsEdit = () => {
    const {mainnews, isLoading, isError, message} = useSelector((state)=>state.mainnews);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const {id} = useParams();
    
useEffect(()=>{
    if(isError){
        window.alert(message);
    }
    dispatch(getMainNews(id))
}, [isError, message, dispatch,id]);
const savedData = {
    ressort:"",
    theme:"",
    title:"",
    content:"",
}
const [data, setData] = useState(savedData);
useEffect(()=>{
    if(mainnews){
        setData({ 
            ressort: mainnews.ressort,
            theme: mainnews.theme,
            title: mainnews.title,
            content:mainnews.content,
        })
    }
}, [mainnews]);

//img
const [fileData, setFileData] = useState({img:""})
const {img} = fileData;
const fileInput = useRef(img);

const fileChange = (e)=>{
    const file = fileInput.current.files[0];
      setFileData(file); 
    handlePreview(file)
  }
  console.log(fileData);
  const [preview, setPreview] = useState(false)
  const handlePreview = (file)=>{
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onloadend = ()=>{
      setPreview(reader.result);
    }
  }

const {ressort, theme, title, content} = data;
console.log(data);
const onSubmit = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const mainnewsData = new FormData();
    mainnewsData.append("ressort", data.ressort);
    mainnewsData.append("theme", data.theme);
    mainnewsData.append("title", data.title);
    mainnewsData.append("content", data.content);
    mainnewsData.append("img", fileData);
   for(let value of mainnewsData){
        console.log(value);
   }
    dispatch(updateMainNews(mainnewsData))
}
```

That is my form:

```
 <MainNewsForm onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <Formgroup>
            <Label htmlFor="img">Image</Label>
            <Input type="file" name="img" id="img"style={{background:"var(--blue)", color:"var(--white)"}} accept=".png, .jpg" onChange={fileChange} ref={fileInput}/>
             {preview ? <img src={preview} alt={preview} title={preview} style={{height:"200px", width:"400px"}}/> :
           <img src={mainnews.img} alt="savedImg" title="savedImg" style={{height:"200px", width:"300px"}}/>}
        </Formgroup>
        <Formgroup>
            <Label htmlFor="ressort">Ressort</Label>
            <Input type="text" name="ressort" id="ressort" defaultValue={ressort} onChange={(e)=>setData({...data, ressort: e.target.value})}/>
        </Formgroup>
        <Formgroup>
            <Label htmlFor="theme">Theme</Label>
            <Input type="text" name="theme" id="theme" defaultValue={theme} onChange={(e)=>setData({...data, theme: e.target.value})}/>
        </Formgroup>
        <Formgroup>
            <Label htmlFor="title">Title</Label>
            <Input type="text" name="title" id="title" defaultValue={title}  onChange={(e)=>setData({...data, title: e.target.value})}/>
        </Formgroup>
        <Formgroup>
            <Label htmlFor="content">Content</Label>
            <Textarea type="text" name="content" id="content" defaultValue={content}  onChange={(e)=>({...data, content: e.target.value})}></Textarea>
        </Formgroup>
        <ButtonHolder>
            <UpdateButton type="submit">Update</UpdateButton>
        </ButtonHolder>
    </MainNewsForm>
```

Answer (score 1):

`onChange={updateData}` does not work since your change handler is written as a higher order function that returns a change handler that is custom for the specific inputs. `onChange={updateData("ressort")}` etc. should work however.

Couple of unrelated things I'd like to mention:

- Using capitalized html tags like `<Input` looks a bit confusing, like you're using Material UI. The convention is that those are your own classes/component names or come from a library. I'd stick to lowercase html tags.
- I would not put `FormData` in redux. If there is an async action that calls the backend, then somewhere in the action creator (or some sort of API client) is a better place to transform the data, if the API expects classic FormData. React doesn't need to be concerned with that.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer timotgl, but sadly it not works. When I write it like this, it tells me that there is no onChange method in the inputfield. I tried it also with onChange={()=>updataData("ressort"), but without any change. By the way, I use styled-components, thats why the html tags are capitalized. Concerning transforming the data, I have to think a bit over it.

Comment: @Roman There 100% is an `onChange` handler on plain text inputs in React. Please check what these `<Input>` are actually rendered as. We can't see your imports for that snippet. They possibly get rendered as another html element, you can verify that in the browser.

Comment: when I put the setData directly into the form, then it is okay with the onChange. But I have still the same error, cannot write anything in my textarea, the other fields are rewriteable and obviously it finds not the e.target.files.

Comment: Using deffaultValue solved the issue with the textarea.